# python - Как вводить параметры для программы, которая будет запускаться в другой консоли?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, консоль

У меня есть программа (main.py), которая должна в процессе своей работы запускать другую(test.py):

**main.py**

```
call(["python3.7", "/home/dlenskyi/Desktop/test.py", "a", "b"] + sys.argv[1:])
```

**test.py**

```
print(sys.argv[1])
```

Если вывести, например, первый параметр, то все будет работать. В той же консоли, где запущена моя первая программа, будет напечатан результат для второй программы.

Вопрос: у меня стоит задача открыть вторую программу не в этой же консоли, где запущена главная, а в новой, причем передать также ей аргументы, и вывести их на экран, но выдает ошибку, что якобы я ввожу 0 параметров.
Вот команда, с помозью которой я пытаюсь это реализовать:

```
call(["gnome-terminal", "--command", "python3.7 /home/dlenskyi/Desktop/main.py", "a", "b"] + sys.argv[1:])
```

Как можно решить эту проблему? Есть ли альтернативы?

Answer (score 0):

Может быть - так?

Первая программа:

```
import sys
import subprocess

cmd2 = "python /home/dlenskyi/Desktop/p2.py a b "
for s in sys.argv[1:]:
    cmd2 = cmd2 + " " + s

subprocess.call(["gnome-terminal", "-e", cmd2])
```

Вторая программа:

```
import sys
import time

print("Вторая программа")
print(sys.argv[1:])
time.sleep(10)
```

Строка запуска первой программы:

```
$ python p1.py c d
```

Результат работы второй программы:

```
Вторая программа
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Comment: Cпасибо огромное!! Все работает)

Comment: @Денис Галочку только поставьте, что вопрос решён! :-)